# Unable to reach array->dict->set

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, set, swift2

I want to use my set in a dictionary which is in an array. But I am not able to reach it. Here is the code.

```
class data: UIView {

    func myFunc() {

        var arr: Array<Dictionary<String,Any>> = []

        var dict: Dictionary<String,Any> = [:]

        dict.updateValue("Title1", forKey: "title")
        dict.updateValue("Direction 1", forKey: "directions")
        dict.updateValue(Set(["Item1"]), forKey: "items")

        arr.append(dict)

        dict.updateValue("Title2", forKey: "title")
        dict.updateValue("Direction 2", forKey: "directions")
        dict.updateValue(Set(["Item2"]), forKey: "items")

        arr.append(dict)
```

When I write

```
let set1 = arr[0]["items"] as? Set<String> ?? Set<String>()
```

than I want to use this set

```
data.myFunc.set1
```

the problem is , its giving me just the data.myFunc() property with parentheses . So I am not able to get in. What am I doing wrong . Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access a variable through a function. Instead in this case I would suggest you to return the set or store it in your class for later access:

```
class Data: UIView {
    var set = Set<String>()

    func myFunc() -> Set<String> {
        ...
        let set1 = arr[0]["items"] as? Set<String> ?? Set<String>()

        // store it
        set = set1

        // or return it
        return set1
    }
}

// access
let data = Data()

// fist way
data.myFunc()
let newSet = data.set

// second way
let newSet = data.myFunc()
```

To return the set is mostly the preferred way.

Comment: Everyting is good but I have a problem with last step. I called Data() with let data but after calling your last line data.myFunc() it says - instance member 'data' cannot be used on type 'toolsPage' (which is another viewController page)

Answer (score 1):

I simplified your syntax and came up with the following:

```
func myFunc() {

    var arr = [[String : Any]]()
    var dict = [String : Any]()

    dict["title"] = "Title1"
    dict["directions"] = "Direction 1"
    dict["items"] = Set(arrayLiteral:"Item1")

    arr.append(dict)

    if let set1 = arr[0]["items"] as? Set<String> {
        print(set1)
    }
}

myFunc()
```

The output of this is:

```
["Item1"]
```

Comment: sorry, i didn't see your answer :-). one note arrayLiteral: "Item1" doesn't describe really an array ...

Answer (score 0):

```
func myFunc() {

    var arr = [[String : Any]]()
    var dict = [String : Any]()

    dict["title"] = "Title1"
    dict["directions"] = "Direction 1"
    dict["items"] = Set(["Item1","Item2"])

    arr.append(dict)

    if let set1 = arr[0]["items"] as? Set<String> {
        print(set1, set1.dynamicType)
    }
}

myFunc()
```

the output is

```
["Item2", "Item1"] Set<String>
```

as expected ...